# Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw ;nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm, stack-overflow

[image: Diagram]
[image: CandidateProfileSaved.class]
[image: Address.class]
[image: Role.class]
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name = "Posting")
public class Posting implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "job_name")
@FullTextField()
private String jobName;

@Column(name = "position")
@FullTextField()
private String position;

@Column(name = "degree_required")
private String degreeRequired;

@Column(name = "quantity_needed")
private String quantityNeeded;

@Column(name = "descriptions", length = 3000)
@FullTextField()
private String description;

@Column(name = "benefits", length = 3000)
private String benefits;

@Column(name = "profile_included", length = 1000)
private String profileIncluded;

@Column(name = "images", length = 1000)
private String images;

@Column(name = "commission", length = 1000)
private String commission;

@Column(name = "probationary_period")
private String probationaryPeriod;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private Integer quantity;

@Column(name = "gender_requirement")
@FullTextField()
private String genderRequirement;

@Column(name = "job_requirement", length = 4000)
@FullTextField()
private String jobRequirement;

@Column(name = "deadline_for_submission")
private String deadlineForSubmission;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "posting_category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@NotNull
@JsonIgnore
private PostingCategory postingCategory;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "posting_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@NotNull
@JsonIgnore
private PostingType postingType;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "working_form_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonIgnore
private WorkingForm workingForm;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "year_of_experience_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonIgnore
private YearOfExperience yearOfExperience;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "rank_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonIgnore
private Rank rank;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "salary_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonIgnore
private Salary salary;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonIgnore
private Address address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "posting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<SavedJob> savedJob;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "posting", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<AppliedJob> appliedJob;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@NotNull
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

@NotBlank
@Column(name = "recruiter_name")
private String recruiterName;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
@Size(min = 10, max = 10)
@NotBlank(message = "mobileNumber is required")
private String phoneNumber;

@NotBlank
@Column(name = "email_contact")
private String emailContact;

@Column(name = "views")
private Long view;

@Column(name = "files", length = 500)
private String file;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "email", unique = true, length = 100)
private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<CV> cv;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<JobApplication> jobApplication;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<CurriculumVitae> curriculumVitae;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<CoverLetter> coverLetter;

@Builder.Default
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "users_roles",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Address address;

@Column(name = "address")
private String addressName;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "birth_date")
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "career_goals")
private String careerGoals;

@Column(name = "university")
private String university;

@Column(name = "rating")
private String rating;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Notification> notifications;

@Column(name = "maria_status")
private String mariaStatus;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Degree> degrees;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Posting> postings;

@Column(name = "gender")
private String gender;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Language> languages;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Experience> experiences;

@Column(name = "taxt_number")
private Long taxtNumber;

@Column(name = "images")
private String images;

@Column(name = "candidate_cv")
private String candidateCV;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "desired_job_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private DesiredJob desiredJob;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "candidate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Message> candidateMessage;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "recruiter", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<Message> recruiterMessage;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
private CandidateProfileSaved candidateProfileSaved;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<SavedJob> savedJob;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private Collection<AppliedJob> appliedJob;
}
```

I don't know why when I tried to get User by email. I have an repository is UserRepository. But when I get user by email from repository. In my console I not only run query get user by email instead of get candidate profile save, get role, get address and error occur when run get posting by address id
Please help me know why it runs like that

My remote code https://github.com/ericnguyen1606/springboot
[image: Error Image]
[image: get candidate_profile_save & get role]
[image: UserRepository.class]